# Find the 3rd degree of polynomial having trigonometry as a root

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

I am struggling to solve the problem that asking to find the 3rd degree of polynomial having all coefficients as integers, which satisfying 
$f(\cos \frac{\pi}{7})=0$.

I know that I should use the euler's equation, but I don't know how to apply it to this problem.

In detail, I know I should use the fact that $e^{(\frac{\pi i}{7})}$ is the root for $\frac{(x^7+1)}{x+1}$ = $x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1 = 0 $, but it is really hard for me to find how to use that fact to solve the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Oops, my bad. It is pi/7, NOT pi/2.

Comment: My bad again. Sorry for bothering. The unstated condition is that all the coefficient must be integers. Sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**MORE DETAILS**
You want a relation involving only $\;c:=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}7\right)\,$ the real part of $\,x=e^{i\pi/7}\,$ such that :
$$x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1 = 0$$
Divide by $x^3$ to get :

\begin{align}
\tag{1}&\bigl(x^3+x^{-3}\bigr)-\bigl(x^2+x^{-2}\bigr)+\bigl(x^1+x^{-1}\bigr)=1\\
\end{align}

But

\begin{align}
\tag{2}(2\;c)=\left(x+\frac 1x\right)^1&=\bigl(x^1+x^{-1}\bigr)\\
\tag{3}(2\;c)^2=\left(x+\frac 1x\right)^2&=\bigl(x^2+x^{-2}\bigr)+2\\
\tag{4}(2\;c)^3=\left(x+\frac 1x\right)^3&=\bigl(x^3+x^{-3}\bigr)+3\,\bigl(x^1+x^{-1}\bigr)\\
\end{align}
so that everything may be written in function of $\,c\,$ only :

- from $(2)$ and $(4)$ deduce $\,\bigl(x^3+x^{-3}\bigr)=(2\;c)^3-3\,(2\;c)\,$,
- from $(3)$ deduce $\,\bigl(x^2+x^{-2}\bigr)$
- from $(2)\ \cdots$

Conclude !

Comment: Thanks for helping! I really appreciate. But I still don't understand... I got ${cos \t}^3 - 3cos\t sin\t - 2{cos \t}^2+cos\t = 0 , but I think still it is not the polynomial having integer coefficients. How do I deal with $sin \t$ to get a polynomial consisting of $cos \t&?

Comment: @BlockJeong: I updated my answer with more details at the end.

Answer (score 0):

A generic overview for other denominators $n\neq 3$ in $\cos (\pi/n)$ is in https://vixra.org/abs/2210.0026 . This includes $8\cos ^3(\pi/7)-4\cos^2(\pi/7)-4\cos(\pi/7)+1=0$.